# Срабатывает TextChanged при прокрутке RecycleView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, recyclerview

Есть `RecycleView`. Item'ом является `CardView` с `EditText`. В адаптере на `EditText` повешен `addTextChangedListener()`. Но он срабатывает всякий раз, когда я нажимаю вне `RecycleView` или листаю его. С чем это может быть связано и как можно пофиксить?
Спасибо)

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#373737"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="7dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewHabit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/EnterHabit"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="KeyboardInaccessibleWidget,TextViewEdits" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Это в адаптере:

```
holder.habit.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
            println("Срабатывает не тогда, когда нужно:(")
        }
    })
```

Comment: Я вижу в разметке `TextView` а не `EditText`. И в адаптере лучше ничего не обрабатывать, делайте это в основном классе через интерфейс.

Comment: @andrey-mihalev а как можно реализовать интерфейс для addTextChangedListener()? Я знаю только для onClick

Comment: В адаптер можно перебросить лямбда выражение как параметр, и при onTextChanged выполнять лямбда функцию передавая туда p0.

Comment: Эти варианты не работают. Я пока только понял, что именно при добавлении нового элемента в RecycleView или скролле, срабатывает слушатель. То есть он вызывается каждый раз при отрисовке. Но я не могу понять всё равно одного: почему в принципе срабатывает слушатель?? Я же текст не меняю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RecycleView` реализовует [паттерн ViewHolder](https://habr.com/ru/post/258195/).

**Что это за паттерн?** Этот паттерн отвечает за быструю отрисовку UI, для этого единовременно на экране загружено количество элементов равное количеству которое помещается на экране +1. Таким образом у вас есть некое количество `ViewHolder-ов` которые по мере скрола `RecyclerView` заново биндятся.

Не совсем уверен как в точности работает `onTextChanged()`, но я думаю, что при каждом бинде система вызывает этот колбек.

**Как это пофиксить?** Возможно стоит в как-то от него отписываться (но точно не подскажу как). Может быть вам стоит попробовать все же сам слушатель передавать снаружи из `View`, но это тоже не гарантия того, что будет работать.

Comment: Понял) Буду тогда искать способ вынести слушатель за бинд. Спасибо)